# upload multiple images on cloudinary using carrierwave and store entry in database also from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a product_image model, seller controller and seller and a view file
here I am sending you my code

## product_image.rb

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

## seller_controller.rb

```
def add_products

    params[:image].each do |image|
      ProductImage.create(image: image)
    end
    # byebug
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end
```

## view

```
<%= form_tag add_seller_products_path, method: "get", validate: true,html: {multipart: true}  do %>
<%= file_field_tag "image[]", class: "pro-img", multiple: true, accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png", name: "image[]" %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved some portion of my problem: i changed the datatype of image column with `json` and received the strong parameters in an array, like {image: []}, but by doing so images names are being stored into the database table with their original name not in cloudinary encrypted form, and not being stored in cloudinary.
so please someone tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at the following sample project, demonstrating multiple uploads support with Cloudinary on a Rails + CarrierWave project:
https://github.com/taragano/Cloudinary_multiple_uploads